# Keycloak Admin console not accessible

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I'm trying to setup Keycloak on a root server but I cannot access the admin console from the internet.
I've installed the keycloak server and put it behind an nginx reverse proxy on the same machine. I've setup a letsencrypt cert for the domain. I've also setup the admin user for keycloak via script.

When I visit the server with it's domain `https://<my-domain>` I'm forwarded to `https://<my-domain>/auth` and there is the keycloak welcome page with a link to "Administration Console". This link points to `https://<my-domain>/admin` but shows a 404.

At first I thought this might be a problem with nginx so I followed the guide in the docs to setup a load-balancer (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy). There, under "Verify Configuration" it tells you to open the path `https://<my-domain>/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration` which works as expected and I get a json file with several links and other information in it. However, none of those links do work - all give me a 404.

When I try `https://<my-domain>/auth/realms/master` I get a JSON response. 
So some links do work so I think it's not a problem with nginx but with keycloak itself.

So the basic question is: How do I configure Keycloak so that I can access the admin console via internet? I've read that by default you can only access it on localhost but there must be a way to overwrite this default?

The relevant nginx config:

```
upstream keycloak {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # some ssl configuration for letsencrypt

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://keycloak;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    }
}
```

Some parts in `keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` that I've edited:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" ...>
    ...
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" 
            socket-binding="http" 
            redirect-socket="proxy-https"
            enable-http2="true"
            proxy-address-forwarding="true" />
        ...
    </server>
    ...
</subsystem>
...
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address />
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address />
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" ...>
    ...
    <socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443" />
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

EDIT

I was able to fix it. The problem was that keycloak was redirecting the initial page from `https://<my-domain>/` to `https://<my-domain>/auth` but then in all other links this additional `/auth` was missing. So the admin link was pointing to `https://<my-domain>/admin/master/console` without the `/auth` part and this page wasn't existing. When I was manually typing the URL with `/auth` in it I got a page with a "loading.." message but all style and JavaScript files linked where also missing the `/auth` part in their URLs so nothing was working.

To fix this I had now changed in `standalone.xml` the line `<web-context>auth</web-context>` to `<web-context>/</web-context>` and now everything behaves as expected. There is no redirecting anymore at the start page and all links do work without the `/auth` part in it. 
However, it would be interesting why it wasn't working in the first place and how one solve this if the `/auth` redirection was intended.

Comment: I like that the idea you added @Manuel Makes sense to me to exclude the `/auth` part. But it seemed to help for my case, only to add that part to frontendUrl

Comment: Where is this standalone.xml file and how do i edit it ?

Comment: @MoonLight I believe the `standalone.xml` file is part of the old WildFly version of Keycloak and is absent in the Quarkus versions.

Answer (score 21):

You helped me solve my issue. I was setting the java system property `keycloak.frontendUrl` (or env `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL`), and apparently it wants a full url, not just the hostname. Appending `/auth` fixed my redirect problems.

It looks like `keycloak.hostname.fixed.hostname` (`KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME`) may also cause problems if `/auth` isn't appended.

See docs for details on the hostname provider here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#hostname

Comment: page unavailable

Comment: Probably jsut moved to here: https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue with keycloak instances behind nginx reverse proxy in my kubernetes cluster. I fixed it by setting the env PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING to true.  `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`

Comment: I needed to add this when deploying the docker version to an azure app service

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried different settings but only this worked on AWS with an application load balancer (with SSL) + nginx reverse proxy + keycloak 19.0.1

Answer (score 0):

add this ENV KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED=false

Answer (score -3):

Try open 
/auth/admin/master/console/
in a Browser.

Additional Info:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/rest-api/index.html

Oh, and I recommend to use a dockerized Keycloak. The upgrade path to a newer Version if much easier.

Comment: When I open `/auth/admin/master/console/` I see "{{notification.header}} {{notification.message}} Loading...". In the browser devtools I can see that a big number of scripts and css files can't be loaded because of a 404.

Comment: I think the problem is that `/auth` is missing in the generated links. For example the `styles.css` file is references with a link `https://<my-domain>/resources/ik361/admin/keycloak/css/styles.css` which is not available. But if I add `/auth` directly behind the domain like this `https://<my-domain>/auth/resources/ik361/admin/keycloak/css/styles.css` then it works. So the question is: Why is keycloak (or nginx?) removing this part from URLs

Comment: I think that it could be a nginx issue. Can you try to access keycloak from the machine itself? Then you know that its something with nginx.